# What does Sicario have to do with Sabrina the Teenage Witch?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, casting, deadpool-2, sicario, sabrina-the-teenage-witch

In response to Josh Brolin being cast in Deadpool 2, [Ryan Reynolds tweeted](https://twitter.com/VancityReynolds/status/852272220575592452) the following:

> The fuck, Fox! You can't play 2 characters in the same universe!! Josh Brolin was in Sicario and I was in Sabrina The Teenage Witch.

I feel like there's a joke here I'm not getting. How are Sicario and Sabrina the Teenage Witch at all related?

Comment: That's the joke.

Comment: Well, we know Brolin also plays Thanos in the Avengers movies.  I've seen sites mention Sicario/Sabrina and they all seem (to me) as if they're acting like they get the joke but none of them actually explain it.

Comment: I interpret it as a commentary on how Brolin's double dipping in the Marvel pool is not a continuity problem. Thanos and Cable are as much in the same cinematic universe as Deadpool and _Sabrina_. - The humor comes from using _Sicario_, even though it's obviously about Brolin's role in the _MCU_, and _Sabrina_ instead of any other, more famous movie, Ryan Reynolds starred in.

Comment: @Oliver_C It might be referring to one of his other superhero movie roles, rather than just "any other, more famous movie". Likely either the awful "Deadpool" he played in X-Men Origins: Wolverine or his role in Green Lantern (I know that's DC, but not everybody who goes to see these movies does).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That was a joke, as noticed by so many. From [hollywoodreporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/deadpool-2-ryan-reynolds-is-jokingly-upset-cable-casting-993401)

> Josh Brolin's casting as Cable in Fox's Deadpool 2 has been greeted with both joy and confusion online. After all, doesn't Brolin already play Thanos in the Marvel Cinematic Universe? Is that even allowed? (The answer to both: Yes!)
>
> Deadpool star Ryan Reynolds played up those fan anxieties with a
>   tone-perfect tweet.
>
> > "The f—, Fox! You can't play 2 characters in the same universe!! Josh
> >      Brolin was in Sicario and I was in Sabrina The Teenage Witch," he
> >      tweeted Wednesday.
>
> (For the record, Brolin was not in Sabrina the Teenage Witch and
>   Deadpool is not in the same universe as Avengers.)

Ryan just played with the fan confusion.